# How to store data to hbase as json format using Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

This is my log data.

5000 3000

The first field is impression and the second field is view.

Is there a way to transform it to json like this: {"impression":5000,"view":3000} ?

Comment: it seems, that you didn't finish your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging from google. I found this link: https://github.com/rjurney/pig-to-json

It's a udf help pig convert tuple or bag to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using native pig also.

**input.txt**

```
5000 3000
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (impression:long,view:long);
STORE A INTO 'output' USING JsonStorage();
```

**Output:**

```
{"impression":5000,"view":3000}
```

Comment: Thanks ! 
I can't use your solution because i need to store the result to Hbase.